# Creating custom week start and week number

Tags: java, android, jodatime

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants;
import org.joda.time.MutableDateTime;
import org.joda.time.ReadWritableDateTime;
import org.joda.time.Weeks;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class WorkDateUtils {

    private static Context mContext;
    public WorkDateUtils(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the date of the first work date of the first week of the year.
     *  Set it to 01/01 and count forward.
     *  setting DayOfWeek(FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK) can get us into last year, and I want
     *  that to be -1 with the first whole week of the current year as 0.
     */
    public static DateTime getFirstWorkDateOfYear(int year, int first_day) {
        ReadWritableDateTime readWritableDateTime = new MutableDateTime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        while (readWritableDateTime.getDayOfWeek() != first_day) {
            readWritableDateTime.addDays(1);
        }
        return readWritableDateTime.toDateTime();
    }
    /**
     * Get the date of the beginning of the week containing the current day.
     *
     */
    public static DateTime getStartOfWorkWeek(DateTime dateTime, int first_day) {
        ReadWritableDateTime readWritableDateTime = dateTime.toMutableDateTime();
        readWritableDateTime.setMillisOfDay(0);
        while (readWritableDateTime.getDayOfWeek() != first_day) {
            readWritableDateTime.addDays(-1);
        }

        // Make sure we have the right week.
        while (readWritableDateTime.isAfter(dateTime)) {
            readWritableDateTime.addWeeks(-1);
        }

        return readWritableDateTime.toDateTime();
    }

    public static Week workWeekNumber(DateTime workDate) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        final Integer FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = preferences.getInt("workweek_start", DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY);

        Week workWeek = new Week();
        int week;

        DateTime firstWorkDate = getFirstWorkDateOfYear(workDate.getYear(), FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK);

        DateTime firstOfWeek = getStartOfWorkWeek(workDate, FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK);

        workWeek.setWeekStart(firstOfWeek.withTime(0, 0, 0, 0).toString());
        workWeek.setWeekEnd(firstOfWeek.plusDays(6).withTime(23, 59, 59, 999).toString());

        week = Weeks.weeksBetween(firstWorkDate, firstOfWeek).getWeeks();
        workWeek.setWeekNum(week);

        return workWeek;
    }
}
```

I've run this through tests for entire years and not seen any issues, but this will get called heavily, and hoping to optimize it as much as I can.

the Weeks class is just a holder to pass everything around.

Comment: as I know the `jodatime` library works **not** quickly on Android. [Stackoverflow - Joda Date is slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059663/android-java-joda-date-is-slow)

Comment: I tried with both calendar/date and Android's Time, neither worked too well, so I settled on joda in order to get working in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need to iterate, just do the (mod 7) math to get the correct date directly:

```
public static DateTime getFirstWorkDateOfYear(int year, int firstDay) {
    ReadWritableDateTime readWritableDateTime = new MutableDateTime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    int doW = readWritableDateTime.getDayOfWeek();
    readWritableDateTime.addDays((7 + firstDay - doW) % 7);
    return readWritableDateTime.toDateTime();
}

public static DateTime getStartOfWorkWeek2(DateTime dateTime, int firstDay) {
    ReadWritableDateTime readWritableDateTime = dateTime.toMutableDateTime();
    readWritableDateTime.setMillisOfDay(0);
    int doW = readWritableDateTime.getDayOfWeek();
    readWritableDateTime.addDays(((firstDay - doW - 7) % 7));
    return readWritableDateTime.toDateTime();
}
```

The technique proposed is not particularly dependent on which date library you use; with minor variations it can be applied to normal Date or Calendar types.  While I like joda, in general, I have no opinion on its performance on Android.